# Generic linked list - how to add different objects

Tags: java, generics, linked-list

I have created a linked list, but I can't seem to understand how to insert different objects into the same list. Let's say I have a list which I want to contain both objects of type cat and dog, is this possible? I know how to insert only cats, or only dogs, but I can't seem to understand how to insert both into the same list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use their "lowest" common class, or a common interface, so you can tell as much as possible (and what you need) about list's elements.

If both classes `Dog` and `Cat` **extend the class** `Animal`, and you want to represent a list of animals, you can do:

```
List<Animal> animals = new YourList<Animal>();
for (Animal animal: animals){
    // use some Animal method
    animal.eat();
}
```

If both of them **implement the interface** `TailOwner` and you want to use operations from that interface on members of the list, you can do:

```
List<TailOwner> tailOwners = new YourList<TailOwner>();
for (TailOwner tailOwner: tailOwners){
    // use some TailOwner method
    tailOwner.wiggle();
}
```

If you're not sure, you can always fall back to `Object`, as all Java classes extend it:

```
List<Object> objects = new YourList<Object>();
for (Object object: objects){
    // use some Object method
    System.out.println(tailOwner.toString());
}
```

Usually, when you have two objects in the same list, they do have **something** in common.

Either way, you're giving up any `Cat`-specific or `Dog`-specific methods (before casting back to either) when you put them in the list.

Having a good hierarchy can prevent casting, and promote polymorphism, when you use objects from the list. All you can tell about objects retrieved from the list at compile time, is that they at least comply to the list's generic type.

Answer (score 1):

If `Cat` and `Dog` have nothing in common, you can parameterize the `LinkedList` with `Object`:

```
List<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
```

This way you will be able to add both `Cat` and `Dog`, but please note that this may force you to check the types every time you retrieve the objects from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You only can add elements that `implements` same interface or `extends` same class.

```
class Animal {}

class Cat extends Animal{}

class Dog extends Animal{}

List<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<Animal>;
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Dog());
```

OR

```
interface Animal {}

class Cat implements Animal{}

class Dog implements Animal{}

List<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<Animal>;
animals.add(new Cat());
animals.add(new Dog());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your list probably contains elements that are somehow related, it would be best to make an interface and use that as list object type.

Derive both Cat and Dog from IAnimal and make the list of type

```
List<IAnimal> animals = new YourList<IAnimal>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be cautious when using the word generic, especially since cat and dog are not generic.

```
LinkedList<Object> linkedlist = new LinkedList<Object>();
linkedList.add(new Dog());
linkedList.add(new Cat());
```